# edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener

Tags: android

I am interested in how to make a custom keyboard on android and i look this page

http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

i do not understand one methods in this page.i try but every time i found different meanings.

if anybody know this page help me please what does focus_listener.writer wrote this coupled edittext. i know that we create new Edittext Onkey methods .and i understood that when we click edittext , it makes copy and when its make copy focus change ? after when we click edittext again while keyborad is visible , because of copy visible edittext there are no focus change and our keyboard is get unvisible. i understand that but completely i belive i make mistake.help me please

```
             // Find the EditText
            EditText edittext= (EditText)findViewById(...);

              // Make the custom keyboard appear
             edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
             @Override public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if( hasFocus ) showCustomKeyboard(v); else hideCustomKeyboard();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `OnFocusChangeListener` is called?

> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the focus state of a view changed.

What is `onFocusChange`?

> abstract void  onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
>
> Called when the focus state of a view has changed.

It's very simple, when you as user click on a EditText, it will get the "focus" and Android will show the system keyboard to let user write something inside it. Since you want to show your custom keyboard instead of the default everytime a EditText (or everything you want) gets the focus you call the method `showCustomKeyboard` which is:

```
public void showCustomKeyboard( View v ) {
    mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mKeyboardView.setEnabled(true);
    if( v!=null ) ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

`mKeyboardView` is our keyboard which should be showed instead of the original, while this line:

```
if( v!=null ) ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

is used to hide the default the keyboard (`hideSoftInputFromWindow`)

If you understand what i said above, you can understand what `else hideCustomKeyboard();` means, it works like normal Android, when the user leave the EditText we don't need anymore to show the keyboard but since this time it's **your** keyboard you should care about show/hide it

---

> "it makes copy and when its make copy focus change ?"

I don't understand what you mean, it don't copy anything.

> "after when we click edittext again while keyborad is visible , because of copy visible edittext there are no focus change and our keyboard is get unvisible"

No, if you click again the same EditText it will still have the focus, the keyboard will be hidden when you change the focus

Comment: OWW my god i forget i understant firsly like u but after i say how we can hide keybord like 2 touch edittittext  we cannnot hide keyboard wiht 2 touch edittext ok thanks.